# What is a lightweight way to monitor a network adapter in Java?

Tags: java, windows, networking

I want to be able to detect when a computer connects to a network. The environment is Java 5  under Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your choices are to either use some JNI library (though I'm not familiar with one offhand and that would tend to be platform specific), or just try making a network connection to some known IP (google for example).  Neither solution is elegant, but I don't believe there is a pure Java API in 1.5 for determining this.

In Java 1.6, you could use java.net.NetworkInterface.isUp(), but obviously that won't help for your case of using 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

maybe check in a thread?

```
try {
  InetAddress inetAddr = InetAddress.getByName(host);
  setOnline();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
  setOffline();
}
```

Comment: yes, that would basically work.  Albeit you have to either turn off DNS caching or vary the host that you lookup.  And depending on your specific requirements, this could show a "false" disconnect just b/c of DNS server issues.  I think connecting by IP to a known address might be marginally better.